# AWS - book searching for android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the AWS (Amazon Web Service) in order to search books' details. I have read almost all the explanations at their website but I don't understand which service (EC2, RDS, etc.) I should use.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the Product Advertising API.  Unfortunately the AWS SDK for Android does not offer support for this API.

You may find the content in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595624/amazon-products-api-looking-for-basic-overview-and-information)  to be useful.