# Is there a javascript API to get a book summary based on ISBN?

Tags: javascript, api, isbn

I'm working in a very limited environment and I cannot use any API that requires authentication. The API at https://openlibrary.org would be perfect, but it does not serve a book summary. All I need to do is get a book summary (akin to the back cover of a book) from an ISBN number that I pass.

I have to use javascript because I only have access to the client-side code.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic in most of [se] network. Please, refer to the [help] to know what's on-topic in each site.

Comment: I don't agree that he's looking for vague recommendations here. He has a very specific requirement and is looking for very specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Amazon's Product Advertising API documentation:

- [ItemLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html)
- [EditorialReview Response Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_EditorialReview.html)

You should be able to, without authentication, pull up the Product Description for a book using a request to:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
    Service=AWSECommerceService&
    AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
    Operation=ItemLookup&
    ItemId=[ISBN]&
    IdType=ISBN&
    ResponseGroup=EditorialReview&
    Condition=All&
    Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]&
    Signature=[Request Signature]
```

Yes, you may have to sign up for an Amazon access key, and there may be rate-limiting which applies to your request, but this *should* get you there without maintaining a user authentication session.

Comment: However, the Product Advertising API may be deprecated (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595624/amazon-products-api-looking-for-basic-overview-and-information#comment13332210_1693376), look for Amazon Marketplace Web Service (MWS)(https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A Google Web Search API might be helpful too (https://www.google.com/search?q=0596002068&)

Then consequently scrape the first result using something like https://www.mashape.com/warting/scrapegoat#!endpoint-scrapePrerendered

I was able to get the summary of the book like below:

[image]