# Amazon MWS API - Searching Products

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've recently been trying to gather a small database of books that I have ISBNs for. My options are limited because I need, among other things, a description, which isn't common in services like this. From what I've gathered, one of the best ways to do this is using Amazon's API.

I've been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979137/is-there-a-javascript-api-to-get-a-book-summary-based-on-isbn) where people recommended using Amazon's API, and both there and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595624/amazon-products-api-looking-for-basic-overview-and-information#comment13332210_1693376) they mentioned that the old way used in those answers is now deprecated. Unfortunately, Amazon's own documentation for this thing is horrifically terrible, and I can't seem to find any resources to use it.

Does anyone have tips on what to do, or good places to learn how to do this with Amazon? If there are better alternatives, I'm also glad to take those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this in two steps:

1. use Amazon's API to request the store URL of the book in question

[details on the API request from the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyISBN.html).

2. Amazon's API won't respond with the description you need, but it will respond with the URL of the page which contains that description. All you'll need to do is crawl that page, perhaps with something like [npm crawler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler).

You'll find the description after the `<div id="bookDescription_feature_div" class="feature" data-feature-name="bookDescription">` div of the crawled page.