# Amazon Products Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I was looking around web and  amazon affilate apis, but can not find a way without scrapping amazon product pages  to extract some of the data to display on my site.

I have  input box where users can copy/past amazon links and I want to create preview to the product on next page using the image, price and other content and link back to the page. I saw this [Amazon products API - Looking for basic overview and information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595624/amazon-products-api-looking-for-basic-overview-and-information), I have try to use id that I think was correct one to get data for but I got wrong result.

Example 
[https://www.amazon.com/Hello-Kitty-Petite-House-Complete/dp/B00I90NTCE/ref=sr_1_2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I90NTCE)

I assume this is B00I90NTCE the id.

Can someone point me to correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

Well you should read the documentation for the amazon product api. Here is a link to the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html. You can also try out the api using the scratch pad: http://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html?rw_useCurrentProtocol=1. See also this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/SubmittingYourFirstRequest.html

The amazon api is RESTful which means it is stateless and it works over http. It is easy to use. you have to create a url with the required parameters. if you call this url from a programming language or copy/paste it in a browser, it will return xml. The xml will contain the product information such as product image, price, product description, amazon link etc. You can parse the xml using a suitable library for your programming language