# Extract Products/Prices/Categories/Specs from Amazon Inventory

Tags: python, django, amazon-product-api

I am a Django developer and recently I got some project where I need to render Amazon's inventory to Django website. Is there some sort of solution that allows Amazon.com to share their products or do I have to manage it with **scraper** .

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595624/amazon-products-api-looking-for-basic-overview-and-information

Comment: This doesn't say much for rendering items from Amazon eCommerce site to my own site I am building in Django.

Comment: `The Product Advertising API lets you leverage Amazon’s customer-centric features such as Product Search, Customer Reviews, Similar Products, Accessories, Wish Lists and more`. anything more you need on your site ?

Comment: If I can create a replica of Amazon for few categories then this would be wonderful. Can I?

Comment: The official api is enough to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've developed a project recently using Amazon Product Advertising API. The project is not live yet so I couldn't give you a live example. But to get started...[This](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api) is the link for you to get started. It worked for me and would worked for you. If you can start working on the project you can post your issues here or directly to Git [Issues](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api/issues) for help for Django/Flask or any Python framework. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much because this is exactly what I needed. :-)