# Can I use AWS to get product descriptions about Amazon.com retail products?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm really new with amazon.

What I want to do is to get amazon product descriptions to my localhost server by using product ASIN number and PHP (can i do this???). I haven't done this before and don't know how to perform this action.

I think that just scraping the price from the Amazon website is bad idea and better to use an API. Can I use Amazon AWS for this? I have created an account in https://aws.amazon.com/ (is this the right place?) and see this [big screen with many amazon aws options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM2OQ.png).

Surfing in internet I found some examples but I think I need keyId, secretKey, associateId - to try this example. Can somebody help be get a better understanding of what to do and where to look? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon products API - Looking for basic overview and information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595624/amazon-products-api-looking-for-basic-overview-and-information)

Comment: No, its not aws, its mws. Look here https://developer.amazonservices.com

Answer (score 3):

If you are not familiar with AWS that's a fair assumption to make.

Actually AWS is completely separate to Amazon.com (the online retailer).

[Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is-aws/?nc2=h_ql_le) is a cloud computing platform that allows you to run virtual servers, databases, storage, and many higher level managed services. You should consider running your PHP server on there, a good starting point for absolute beginners is [LightSail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/getting-started-with-amazon-lightsail), where you can create a LAMP stack in minutes.

Back to your original question, to get product details you need to use [Amazon Marketplace Web Services (MWS)](https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/), specifically the [GetMatchingProductForId](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_GetMatchingProductForId.html) and pass in your ASIN number.

See here for a [PHP Example](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProductForIdRequest/-/php-marketplacewebserviceproducts_model_getmatchingproductforidrequest-class-examples.html#0x575bdbeec5a45b40a9290ae1adebc3100cb423552369c4083f874aa4c70471b9-392,,444,), the important parts of that example, for you to expand on, are:

```
public function getProductById($ProductID, $IdType = 'ASIN') {
    $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProductForIdRequest();
    $request->setSellerId($this->MySellerId);
    $request->setMarketplaceId($this->MyMarketplaceId);
    $request->setIdType($IdType);
    if (!is_array($ProductID)) {
        $ProductID = array($ProductID);
    }
    $idList = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_IdListType();
    $idList->setId($ProductID);
    $request->setIdList($idList);
    $response = $this->service->GetMatchingProductForId($request);
    return $response;
}
```