# how to get amazon web store product list API ? i want to get the list of products that is available on my store

Tags: api, amazon-product-api

i know we can create a store on amazon to sell our products. is there any api or method for getting the product list of my store through API call ?

Comment: This question seems almost identical to this previous one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595624/amazon-products-api-looking-for-basic-overview-and-information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon products API - Looking for basic overview and information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595624/amazon-products-api-looking-for-basic-overview-and-information)